# output is not what was expected FASM BootLoader org 0x7c00

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, fasm, bochs

output is not what was expected FASM BootLoader org 0x7c00

```
use16 
 
org 0x7c00
 
    message db "Hello!"
    len equ $ - message
 
BootLoader:
    cli
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xFFFF
    sti

    mov ax, 0002h
    int 10h

    mov bx, 0
    mov dx, 1
    
    mov cx, len

print_loop:

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, [message + bx]
    
    int 10h
    
    inc bx
    cmp bx, len
    
    jl print_loop

    jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0 
dw 0xAA55
```

[image]

Using Bochs 2.7 I expected the text "Hello!"

Comment: You are going to want to use `=` instead of `equ`. FASM is a bit of an anomaly among assemblers in that `EQU` does text replacement and doesn't compute expressions. So change `len equ $ - message` to `len = $ - message`. You will also want to move the `message` (data) after your code. Placed at the top the CPU will start executing the message `hello` as code. Place the data after the last instruction in the bootloader but before the boot signature 0xaa55.